# how to convert functional component to class component in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

This is the Table by Ant Design in there example all the examples are in functional component and I need a class component

In my project I have used class components rather than functional components as I am getting all function components in every website. Can you help me to convert functional component to class component.

```
import { SearchOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import type { InputRef } from 'antd';
import { Button, Input, Space, Table } from 'antd';
import type { ColumnsType, ColumnType } from 'antd/es/table';
import type { FilterConfirmProps } from 'antd/es/table/interface';
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import Highlighter from 'react-highlight-words';

interface DataType {
  key: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
  address: string;
}

type DataIndex = keyof DataType;

const data: DataType[] = [
  {
    key: '1',
    name: 'John Brown',
    age: 32,
    address: 'New York No. 1 Lake Park',
  },
  {
    key: '2',
    name: 'Joe Black',
    age: 42,
    address: 'London No. 1 Lake Park',
  },
  {
    key: '3',
    name: 'Jim Green',
    age: 32,
    address: 'Sidney No. 1 Lake Park',
  },
  {
    key: '4',
    name: 'Jim Red',
    age: 32,
    address: 'London No. 2 Lake Park',
  },
];

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
  const [searchedColumn, setSearchedColumn] = useState('');
  const searchInput = useRef<InputRef>(null);

  const handleSearch = (
    selectedKeys: string[],
    confirm: (param?: FilterConfirmProps) => void,
    dataIndex: DataIndex,
  ) => {
    confirm();
    setSearchText(selectedKeys[0]);
    setSearchedColumn(dataIndex);
  };

  const handleReset = (clearFilters: () => void) => {
    clearFilters();
    setSearchText('');
  };

  const getColumnSearchProps = (dataIndex: DataIndex): ColumnType<DataType> => ({
    filterDropdown: ({ setSelectedKeys, selectedKeys, confirm, clearFilters }) => (
      <div style={{ padding: 8 }}>
        <Input
          ref={searchInput}
          placeholder={`Search ${dataIndex}`}
          value={selectedKeys[0]}
          onChange={e => setSelectedKeys(e.target.value ? [e.target.value] : [])}
          onPressEnter={() => handleSearch(selectedKeys as string[], confirm, dataIndex)}
          style={{ marginBottom: 8, display: 'block' }}
        />
        <Space>
          <Button
            type="primary"
            onClick={() => handleSearch(selectedKeys as string[], confirm, dataIndex)}
            icon={<SearchOutlined />}
            size="small"
            style={{ width: 90 }}
          >
            Search
          </Button>
          <Button
            onClick={() => clearFilters && handleReset(clearFilters)}
            size="small"
            style={{ width: 90 }}
          >
            Reset
          </Button>
          <Button
            type="link"
            size="small"
            onClick={() => {
              confirm({ closeDropdown: false });
              setSearchText((selectedKeys as string[])[0]);
              setSearchedColumn(dataIndex);
            }}
          >
            Filter
          </Button>
        </Space>
      </div>
    ),
    filterIcon: (filtered: boolean) => (
      <SearchOutlined style={{ color: filtered ? '#1890ff' : undefined }} />
    ),
    onFilter: (value, record) =>
      record[dataIndex]
        .toString()
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes((value as string).toLowerCase()),
    onFilterDropdownOpenChange: visible => {
      if (visible) {
        setTimeout(() => searchInput.current?.select(), 100);
      }
    },
    render: text =>
      searchedColumn === dataIndex ? (
        <Highlighter
          highlightStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#ffc069', padding: 0 }}
          searchWords={[searchText]}
          autoEscape
          textToHighlight={text ? text.toString() : ''}
        />
      ) : (
        text
      ),
  });

  const columns: ColumnsType<DataType> = [
    {
      title: 'Name',
      dataIndex: 'name',
      key: 'name',
      width: '30%',
      ...getColumnSearchProps('name'),
    },
    {
      title: 'Age',
      dataIndex: 'age',
      key: 'age',
      width: '20%',
      ...getColumnSearchProps('age'),
    },
    {
      title: 'Address',
      dataIndex: 'address',
      key: 'address',
      ...getColumnSearchProps('address'),
      sorter: (a, b) => a.address.length - b.address.length,
      sortDirections: ['descend', 'ascend'],
    },
  ];

  return <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} />;
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Why do you want class components? It is recommended to use Functional components since it is simpler to write and maintain.

Comment: Totally agree with @vighnesh153 
If you want to have access to the lifecycle methods, they don't do you a big favor in maintaining the component in the future.
You might want to look into component hooks (useState, useEffect,...). 
They are robust, easy to use and make the code a lot more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component, createRef, MutableRefObject } from "react";
import { Button, Input, Space, Table } from "antd";
import type { InputRef } from "antd";
import { SearchOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";
import type { ColumnsType, ColumnType } from "antd/es/table";
import type { FilterConfirmProps } from "antd/es/table/interface";
import Highlighter from "react-highlight-words";

interface DataType {
  key: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
  address: string;
}

type DataIndex = keyof DataType;

const data: DataType[] = [
  {
    key: "1",
    name: "John Brown",
    age: 32,
    address: "New York No. 1 Lake Park",
  },
  {
    key: "2",
    name: "Joe Black",
    age: 42,
    address: "London No. 1 Lake Park",
  },
  {
    key: "3",
    name: "Jim Green",
    age: 32,
    address: "Sidney No. 1 Lake Park",
  },
  {
    key: "4",
    name: "Jim Red",
    age: 32,
    address: "London No. 2 Lake Park",
  },
];

interface IState {
  searchText: string;
  searchedColumn: string;
}

class App extends Component<any, IState> {
  state: IState = { searchText: "", searchedColumn: "" };

  searchInput = createRef() as MutableRefObject<InputRef>;

  handleSearch(selectedKeys: string[], confirm: (param?: FilterConfirmProps) => void, dataIndex: DataIndex) {
    confirm();
    this.setState({
      searchText: selectedKeys[0],
      searchedColumn: dataIndex,
    });
  }

  handleReset(clearFilters: () => void) {
    clearFilters();
    this.setState({ searchText: "" });
  }

  getColumnSearchProps(dataIndex: DataIndex): ColumnType<DataType> {
    return {
      filterDropdown: ({ setSelectedKeys, selectedKeys, confirm, clearFilters }) => (
        <div style={{ padding: 8 }}>
          <Input
            ref={this.searchInput}
            placeholder={`Search ${dataIndex}`}
            value={selectedKeys[0]}
            onChange={(e) => setSelectedKeys(e.target.value ? [e.target.value] : [])}
            onPressEnter={() => this.handleSearch(selectedKeys as string[], confirm, dataIndex)}
            style={{ marginBottom: 8, display: "block" }}
          />
          <Space>
            <Button
              type='primary'
              onClick={() => this.handleSearch(selectedKeys as string[], confirm, dataIndex)}
              icon={<SearchOutlined />}
              size='small'
              style={{ width: 90 }}
            >
              Search
            </Button>
            <Button onClick={() => clearFilters && this.handleReset(clearFilters)} size='small' style={{ width: 90 }}>
              Reset
            </Button>
            <Button
              type='link'
              size='small'
              onClick={() => {
                confirm({ closeDropdown: false });
                this.setState({
                  searchText: (selectedKeys as string[])[0],
                  searchedColumn: dataIndex,
                });
              }}
            >
              Filter
            </Button>
          </Space>
        </div>
      ),
      filterIcon: (filtered: boolean) => <SearchOutlined style={{ color: filtered ? "#1890ff" : undefined }} />,
      onFilter: (value, record) =>
        record[dataIndex]
          .toString()
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes((value as string).toLowerCase()),
      onFilterDropdownOpenChange: (visible) => {
        if (visible) {
          setTimeout(() => this.searchInput.current?.select(), 100);
        }
      },
      render: (text) =>
        this.state.searchedColumn === dataIndex ? (
          <Highlighter
            highlightStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#ffc069", padding: 0 }}
            searchWords={[this.state.searchText]}
            autoEscape
            textToHighlight={text ? text.toString() : ""}
          />
        ) : (
          text
        ),
    };
  }

  columns: ColumnsType<DataType> = [
    {
      title: "Name",
      dataIndex: "name",
      key: "name",
      width: "30%",
      ...this.getColumnSearchProps("name"),
    },
    {
      title: "Age",
      dataIndex: "age",
      key: "age",
      width: "20%",
      ...this.getColumnSearchProps("age"),
    },
    {
      title: "Address",
      dataIndex: "address",
      key: "address",
      ...this.getColumnSearchProps("address"),
      sorter: (a, b) => a.address.length - b.address.length,
      sortDirections: ["descend", "ascend"],
    },
  ];

  render() {
    return <Table columns={this.columns} dataSource={data} />;
  }
}
```